# Can I have an image displayed in an iOS notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I don't see any way to do it according to the payload JSON spec etc. I have seen some instances of people maybe showing symbols for sure. Just wanted to check if there is any undocumented way of doing this via the JSON Notification Payload.

Comment: AFAIK the icon/image is not under our control and it is taken from the app icon

Comment: You can only use emoji, unicode characters in your notifications payload..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The images/symbols you’ve seen were emoji, which you can use in your notification’s message payload.